# Hola estoy haciendo un formulario sencillo. tengo radio buttons quiero que cuando presione el radiobutton aparezca un div

Tags: javascript

Por el momento solo tengo esto pero quiero saber que cuando doy click en el radiobutton aparece el div para poder seguir haciendo otro formulario.

```js
function check(mostrarlibros){
  document.getElementById(mostrarlibros).style.display=document.getElementById(mostrarlibros).style.display==''?'none':'';
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflowES, te recomiendo que des una vuelta por el [tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una buena pregunta.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código `html` del checkbox y el div?, Para que nos podamos hacer una idea de como lo tienes y a lo que te refieres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que por defecto el div "mostrarlibros" tiene el atributo `display` como `none` (para que esté oculto). Entonces hazlo así:

```
function check(mostrarlibros){
    document.getElementById(mostrarlibros).style.display = 
        document.getElementById(mostrarlibros).style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```